# Is there a difference between a slur and legato?

Tags: notation, legato, articulation

Are *legato* and *slur* one and the same? If the two are different, how do I tell which the piece is using? I know the gist of them (as opposed to staccato) but I need to know the specifics. They are notated the same (I believe). I am speaking of a wind instrument. Does this make a difference in the way they are played?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Legato is a technique, whereas a slur is a marking.  As for what a slur denotes, Wikipedia does a pretty good job of handling the distinction between that and legato (see [Slur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slur_%28music%29) and [Legato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legato)).  The most relevant quote from the legato article:

> Legato technique is required for slurred performance, but unlike slurring (as that term is interpreted for some instruments), legato does not forbid rearticulation. In standard notation legato is indicated either with the word legato itself, or by a slur (a curved line) under the notes that are to be joined in one legato group.

The slur article notes that with some wind instruments, you should play each slurred note without using the tongue to rearticulate the note.

Comment: If the two are marked the same, how do you know which to play?

Comment: @Luke Notation tends to vary considerably, so honestly you don't. One method is to refer to recordings of first-class musicians and see what they did, or see if you can find any notes on how to perform the piece. When in doubt I would play anything with a slur marking without rearticulation, and whatever you think fits best when you see the word *legato*.  (Or take up an instrument where you always have to rearticulate like piano :P)

Comment: @Luke: The marking is a slur. Legato just means connected. Can you give an example of how you would play these differently?

Comment: Also worth noting that trombonists, to avoid glissandi, develop a technique called 'legato tongue' that adds a soft articulation between two legato notes in the same partial. This is not necessary for other wind instruments making use of keys or valves.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @NReilingh. I am obviously not very familiar with brass or wind instruments :P

Comment: stringed instruments can do legato, too: does it still apply?

Comment: @Agos I would assume there is no difference between them for strings.  They both seem to indicate that the notes should be played in one bow.